# jQuery check if input is invalid or matches other field

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this code here that checks if my input is empty or not:

```js
$('#confirmationEmail').on({
  invalid: function(e) {
    e.target.setCustomValidity("");
    if (!e.target.validity.valid) {
      e.target.setCustomValidity("A valid email address is required.");
    }
  },
  input: function(e) {
    e.target.setCustomValidity("");
    if ($('#email').val() != $('#confirmationEmail').val()) {
      e.target.setCustomValidity("Email did not match.");
    }
  },
  valid: function(e) {
    e.target.setCustomValidity("");
    if ($('#email').val() != $('#confirmationEmail').val()) {
      e.target.setCustomValidity("Email did not match.");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Here is my HTML:

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email*</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" required />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="confirmationEmail">Confirmation Email*</label>
      <input type="email" name="confirmationEmail" id="confirmationEmail" class="form-control" required />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The part to check if the input is invaild works and display a custom invalid message, but the part about the input matching another input does not work, it does not display a message and the input field is valid. What am I doing wrong?

When I say it does not work I mean that the form submits, I guess because the field is valid so it would submit, so my question would be how do I get the message to appear and as a custom invalid message and se the field to invalid?

Comment: @devlincarnate I added my HTML

Comment: OK, so when I run this in a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zephyr_hex/69rtm2a7/4/), the input matching option seems to work fine for me. Check the console logging I added. You can see it is failing to match as you type each character in the confirmation input, until you complete the confirmation email, and then it matches. But, you are displaying the "doesn't match" for every character typed and never removing that message when the user has finished typing in the confirmation email. I think we need more info about what you mean when you say it doesn't work...

Comment: When I say it does not work I mean that the form submits, I guess because the field is valid so it would submit, so my question would be how do I get the message to appear and as a custom invalid message and se the field to invalid?